# ANDROID - How to get return success from web service in android using httpurlconnection?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I've a return 0 from web services using postman if the data send successfully.

but I'm quite confused how to detect `0` message in android using `HttpURLConnection`

in `HttpClient` I'm using `String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);`

```
String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
Log.d("MainActivity", "INSERT:" + response);
```

but refer to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

there's some code like `getResponseCode()` `getResponseMessage()` but the output is `200` for `getResponseCode()` and `OK` for `getResponseMessage()`

so how to get output of `0` in `HttpURLConnection`?

**EDIT** urlconnection code:

```
try {
    JSONObject job = new JSONObject(log);
    String param1 = job.getString("AuditScheduleDetailID");
    String param2 = job.getString("AuditAnswerId");
    String param3 = job.getString("LocalFindingID");
    String param4 = job.getString("LocalMediaID");
    String param5 = job.getString("Files");
    String param6 = job.getString("ExtFiles");
    Log.d("hasil json", param1 + param2 + param3 + param4 + param5 + param6 + " Kelar id " +
            "pertama");

    URL url = new URL("myurl");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
    jsonParam.put("AuditScheduleDetailID", param1);
    jsonParam.put("AuditAnswerId", param2);
    jsonParam.put("LocalFindingID", param3);
    jsonParam.put("LocalMediaID", param4);
    jsonParam.put("Files", param5);
    jsonParam.put("ExtFiles", param6);

    Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
    os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());

    os.flush();
    os.close();

    int respon = conn.getResponseCode();
    Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
    Log.i("Input", String.valueOf(conn.getInputStream()));
    Log.i("MSG", conn.getResponseMessage());

    conn.disconnect();
} catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is the response from your server? Json/xml/text?

Comment: @diegoveloper response from server is just an `int` i dunno its a text or somewhat

Comment: Put some part of your code

Comment: @diegoveloper edited sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you need to read the data from the server using HttpUrlConnection:

```
try {
    JSONObject job = new JSONObject(log);
    String param1 = job.getString("AuditScheduleDetailID");
    String param2 = job.getString("AuditAnswerId");
    String param3 = job.getString("LocalFindingID");
    String param4 = job.getString("LocalMediaID");
    String param5 = job.getString("Files");
    String param6 = job.getString("ExtFiles");
    Log.d("hasil json", param1 + param2 + param3 + param4 + param5 + param6 + " Kelar id " +
            "pertama");

    URL url = new URL("myurl");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
    jsonParam.put("AuditScheduleDetailID", param1);
    jsonParam.put("AuditAnswerId", param2);
    jsonParam.put("LocalFindingID", param3);
    jsonParam.put("LocalMediaID", param4);
    jsonParam.put("Files", param5);
    jsonParam.put("ExtFiles", param6);

    Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
    os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());

    os.flush();
    os.close();
    InputStream is = null;

    if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            is = conn.getInputStream();// is is inputstream
        } else {
            is = conn.getErrorStream();
        }


        try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        String response = sb.toString();
        //HERE YOU HAVE THE VALUE FROM THE SERVER
        Log.d("Your Data", response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    conn.disconnect();
} catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```